# Python/Locust unique values for each virtual user

Tags: python, locust

I have a working script like this:

```
from locust import HttpUser, between, task
import random
import copy

TS_IDs = [
'10158',
'11016',
'10479',
'10482',
'11045',
'10311',
'10159'
]

values = [
{
    "id": 219468,
    "values": [
        {
            "from": "2023-07-04T08:00:00.000Z",
            "to": "2023-07-04T09:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 33
        }
    ]
}
]

values_new = copy.deepcopy(values)

for index, item in enumerate(values_new):
item["id"] = TS_IDs[index]

print(values_new)


class SaveValues(HttpUser):

def _run_write_ts(self, values_new):
    resp = self.client.put(f'/api/SaveValues', json=values_new,
                           headers={'X-API-KEY': 'AKjCg9hTcYQ=', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'})

    print("Response status code:", resp.status_code)

print(values_new)

@task(1)
def test_save_ts_1(self):
    self._run_write_ts(values_new)
```

So when running this Locust test the console prints only the value structure using the first elemt in the TS_IDs list (10158).

How can I make my script go sequentially through the TS_IDs list for each virtual? (the list is much longer than in this example).

Comment: Is your goal to create _n_ new entries (where _n_ is the size of TS_IDs) to values_new where each entry has the same "values" field but with an ID from TS_IDs?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, I don't believe this has much to do with the libraries you imported. This code uses the "sample value" as a template and creates `n` copies (for `n` IDs) that each uses one of the TS_IDs.

```
from locust import HttpUser, between, task
import random
import copy

TS_IDs = [
'10158',
'11016',
'10479',
'10482',
'11045',
'10311',
'10159'
]

sample_value = \
{
    "id": 219468,
    "values": [
        {
            "from": "2023-07-04T08:00:00.000Z",
            "to": "2023-07-04T09:00:00.000Z",
            "value": 33
        }
    ]
}

values_new = []


for ID in TS_IDs:
    new_value = copy.deepcopy(sample_value)
    new_value["id"] = ID
    values_new.append(new_value)


for val in values_new:
    print(val)
```